# Variable is not being reevaluated outside of loop

Tags: c#

I'm working on a Hackerrank problem and my while loop is not working as I would expect. I have a variable external to the loop that is the sum of two other variables, one of which is updated each loop. Since I have a conditional statement in the loop that includes the variable that is external to the loop, I would expect it to be re-evaluated each loop, but it is not. I can work around this, but want to know why this is the case.

Please see my method below. I would expect kangaroo1Location and kangaroo2Location to be re-evaluated each loop to include the new values of kangaroo1DistanceJumped and kangaroo2DistanceJumped, but they are not.

```
    static string Kangaroo(int x1, int v1, int x2, int v2)
    {
        var kangaroo1DistanceJumped = v1;
        var kangaroo2DistanceJumped = v2;
        var kangaroo1Location = x1 + kangaroo1DistanceJumped;
        var kangaroo2Location = x2 + kangaroo2DistanceJumped;

        while (kangaroo1DistanceJumped <= 10000 && kangaroo2DistanceJumped <= 10000)
        {
            if (kangaroo1Location == kangaroo2Location)
            {
                return "YES";
            }

            kangaroo1DistanceJumped = kangaroo1DistanceJumped + v1;
            kangaroo2DistanceJumped = kangaroo2DistanceJumped + v2;

        }

        return "NO";
    }
```

I know I could just declare the kangaroo1Location and kangaroo2Location variables within the while loop but I've been told to not declare variables within loops, but maybe that advice is no longer relevant.

Comment: What are your inputs?

Comment: "I know I could just declare the kangaroo1Location and kangaroo2Location variables within the while loop" But that´s what you should do. Is there any specific reason why you are not allowed to do this?

Comment: You're confusing statements with functions.  The statement `var kangaroo1Location = x1 + kangaroo1DistanceJumped;` sets the value of `kangaroo1Location` once and once only when the statement executes.  If you want that relationship to persist you need to implement it as a class property which is dynamically recomputed *or* you need to write it as a function which is re-evaluated each loop, *or* you need to simply include the update statement inside the loop.

Comment: You literally need to define them inside

Comment: `int`s are stored by value, not reference. As such the value of `kangaroo1Location` and `kangaroo2Location` are set before the loop and not ever updated again. You could either move these variables inside your loop, or use a delegate function e.g. `var kangaroo1Location = () => x1 + kangaroo1DistanceJumped;`

Comment: Is `var kangaroo1DistanceJumped = v1;` correct? Logically you want to initialize with `x1` and then add `v1` for each step (iteration). I see very similar code inside and outside the loop which is _a major code smell_ for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not assigning new values to the `kangaroo1Location` or `kangaroo2Location` inside the loop. The *only* assignments to those variables are before the loop:

```
var kangaroo1Location = x1 + kangaroo1DistanceJumped;
var kangaroo2Location = x2 + kangaroo2DistanceJumped;
```

These variable assignments aren't declaring a sort of functional relationship that's always true - they're just evaluating an expression (e.g. `x1 + kangaroo1DistanceJumped`) and assigning the result to a variable.

As a simpler example, consider this code:

```
int x = 10;
int y = x;

x = 20;
Console.WriteLine(y);
```

The result will be 10 printed to the console, *not* 20. `x` and `y` are independent variables, it just so happens that `y` is initialized with the value of `x` at some point. Later changes to `x` don't affect `y`. Apply the same logic to your code, and you'll see why it's not working.